# QGIS use item id in print composer for relations

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer

i'm trying to use the item id in the print composer of QGIS to build relations.
for example:
i have a label with the text "test" in it and it has the ID=label1
-> now i have a second label in my print composer and want to show the text of label 1 in this label automatically (and it should change if i change label 1)

is something like this possible?

Comment: I think this is not possible (at the moment). The Item ID has another purpose, see here: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2014-February/025989.html